# What is format from url in AJAX to send POST method with RESPONSE ENTITY

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

I already search tutorial in spring for method POST, insert the data with response entity (without query) and I getting error in ajax. I want to confirm, What is format url from ajax to java? below my assumption:

localhost:8080/name-project/insert?id=1&name=bobby

is the above url is correct? because I failed with this url. the parameter is id and name.

mycontroller:

```
@PostMapping(value={"/insertuser"}, consumes={"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<?> insertUser(@RequestBody UserEntity user) throws Exception {
    Map result = new HashMap();
    userService.insertTabelUser(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);        
}
```

my daoimpl:

```
@Transactional
public String insertUser(UserEntity user) {
    return (String) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
}
```

the code running in swagger (plugin maven) but not run in postman with above url.

Thanks.
Bobby

Comment: Can you tell us which error you are getting?

Comment: You have to pass JSON object to ....{contextpath}/insertuser with POST request. There are lots of resource. Please check: https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/014-post-json-to-spring-rest-webservice/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it seems that you try to pass data via get params (id=1&name=bobby), but using POST http method implies to pass data inside body of http request (in get params, as you did, data is passed in GET method) . So you have to serialize your user data on client side and add this serialized data to request body and sent it to localhost:8080/name-project/insert.

Comment: So, if I use postman, how to send the value for inserting data? thanks

Comment: Try to do like in this picture http://imgur.com/a/8kttp . Also worth mentioning that if you use on client side something lkie jQuery for making AJAX-request, you can try to do like this: $.ajax({
    "url": "/name-project/insert",
    'data': JSON.stringify({id:'1', name: 'bobby'}),
    'type': 'POST',
    'contentType': 'application/json'
});

Answer (score 0):

As above answer suggest. You are trying to pass data as query parameters.but you are not reading those values in your rest API.either you need to read those query parameters in your API and then form an object or try to pass a json serialized object to your Post api as recommendation. Hope it helps.