# send data AJAX to @RequestBody Spring

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

I use response entity and request body for inserting data in spring java but I found an error. 404 not found.

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "insertuserlogin/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserLogin user, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Validation validation, Errors error) {
    Map<?, ?> result = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        String errorMessage = bindingResult.getFieldErrors().iterator().next().getDefaultMessage();
        System.out.println(errorMessage);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    } else {
        uls.saveUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);           
    }
}
```

ajax:

```
    var data = { "description": "string", "id": 10, "username": "barubanget"}
    $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        url : "http://localhost:8085/TaspenNCBSpring/insertuserlogin",
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("success post!");
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("error: " + e);
        }
    });
```

How to fix this problem? what a format data from request body? Thanks. Bobby

Comment: Try to use `@RequestMapping(value = "/insertuserlogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)` instead of `@RequestMapping(value = "insertuserlogin/", method = RequestMethod.POST)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is format from url in AJAX to send POST method with RESPONSE ENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955578/what-is-format-from-url-in-ajax-to-send-post-method-with-response-entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your @RequestMapping value is malformed. Please try to put your slash as the first character.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertuserlogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Please let me know if it is useful for you.